# How to print formatted JSON array in php

Tags: php, arrays, json

I was trying to print some image details as a `JSON` array for that I just wrote a PHP code. Now it is printing only `JSON` objects like `{"image0":"iphone.png","image1":"bbg.jpg"}`, But I want it to be formatted as `{"images":[{"image0":"iphone.png"},{"image1":"bbg.jpg"}]}`. Please someone help me to fix this.

**code**

```
<?php
$return_array = array();
$files = glob('tmp/*');
$files = array_filter($files,create_function('$file','return (!is_dir($file));'));
usort($files,create_function('$a,$b','return filemtime($b) - filemtime($a);'));
foreach($files as $key => $file)
{
   $return_array["image".$key] = basename($file);
}
echo json_encode($return_array);    
?>
```

Comment: The data structure `[{"image0":"iphone.png"},{"image1":"bbg.jpg"}]` makes little sense. Why not have an array of strings? `["iphone.png", "bbg.jpg"]`.

Comment: `echo json_encode(array("images" => $return_array));`???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could write your code like this after your `foreach` construct.

```
$new_arr = array();
foreach($return_array as $k=>$v)
{
 $new_arr['images'][]=array('image'.$k=>$v);
}
echo json_encode($new_arr);
```

Comment: this wont print the '[]'

Comment: @ДмитрийИвановичМенделеев, Can you try now ?

Comment: now it will print 0 th index as [["tmp\/iphone.png"]

Comment: want to eliminate the first '['

Comment: **Nahhh you are contradicting your question .. !** See the output it is exactly what you requested in the question. https://eval.in/149867

Comment: I got the output exactly as '{"images":[["iphone.png"],{"1":"1425328_405486846250283_806381377_o.jpg"},{"2":"bbg.jpg"},{"3":"gmail_bg.JPG"},{"4":"Capture.JPG"},{"5":"bg.jpg"},{"6":"abc.JPG"},{"7":"bg_dark.png"},{"8":"bktile.png"}]}'

Comment: see there are two '[[' in the begining of that out put

Comment: @ДмитрийИвановичМенделеев: Use `array('image'.$k=>$v)` instead.